# Adding column to a SPList

Tags: 2007, list, development, feature, custom-list

Normally I create a New List if I want to add an additional column to a List that already exists in a web.

Wondering what would be the best option, should I create a new list with additional column or if there is any script or something I can use to add column to existing one.

I am using sharepoint 2007 and I have this list on hundred of pages.

Content Type

```
 <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0101">
        <Folder TargetName="Forms/Document" />
      </ContentTypeRef>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" />
    </ContentTypes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a column to the list by doing (a number field in this example):

```
SPList lst = oSPWeb.Lists["List Name"];
SPFieldNumber fld= (SPFieldNumber)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Number.ToString(), "Column Name");
lst.Fields.Add(fld);
lst.Update();
```

However its better to create a content type, create a list and then bind the content type to the list. That way you can manage your lists and columns better than when you constantly keep creating new lists...

Comment: In list schema.xml I have got this, but I am not really sure what its being used for here,

Comment: edited my question